# create p12 certificate in windows for apple push notification

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications

I'm doing push notification (server side) for iPhone in c#. I have "developer_Push_SSL_certi.cer" file.

1. How can i create .p12 certificate from .cer file? or i have to install the above .cer file in my PC?
2. what is the required file to send push notifications in server side(c#).

Please guide me guys, what is the certification process required for APN (server side) in windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install this new certificate (developer_Push_SSL_certi.cer) to your Mac.

Then open KeyChain Access and navigate to Keys from left menu. Find your development certificate.

Expand your certificate you will see both Private and Public lines and right click "Private" one, export this certificate with a password.

Thats enough for sending notifications from windows.

Comment: thanks for replay... whether i have to install any certificate in windows?

Comment: no you don't need to install, just create your c# Certificate object with your file name and password both.

Comment: It won't work for distribution profile. Working fine on development profile

Answer (score 4):

You dont need a mac to convert the certificate just use OpenSSL (http://www.openssl.org)

here are the commands

```
$ openssl x509 -in cert.cer -inform DER -outform PEM -out cert.pem
$ openssl pkcs12 -in key.p12 -out key.pem -nodes
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem -out certName.p12
```