# Confusion about IOS certificates, APNS mainly

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing a hybrid app using Cordova, and i'm getting confused about the certificates issue (total newbie to Apple here).

Now, I think I could manage creating a `.p12` file and build apps. What I don't understand is how do I add the APNS certificate to send/receive push notifications. Do I have to merge files in order to have one `.cer` file which includes the production certificate and the APNS certificate? Or how does it go? Is there a protocol for such a popular build?

I'll appreciate some help to clear out this confusion, i'm using windows so i'm doing everything mainly through openssl. Much thanks for any help!

Comment: This certificate is for server only, you don't need it in your app. The format of push certificate depends on your server implementation. Do you have your own server or you use something like parse.com?

Comment: Thanks for your response, i'm using my own server... So that means I just have to update the server according to the certificates? Do you perhaps know of a good protocol I could follow? :)

Comment: It depends on your server configuration. If you use windows server implementation, i think you should see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557028/create-p12-certificate-in-windows-for-apple-push-notification) answer. If you have php or node implementation - you might need cer file, this may be done with openssl.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I will now focus on each of the topics separately.